# uiscrollview doesn't scroll because of autolayout

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, constraints, autolayout

I know that there are already many answers to my questions, but I've tested each one of these and I still have the problem.
I have a UIScrollView which contains a UIView, I want active autolayout for an animation. But because of this, my scrollview doesn't scroll.

This is my code:

```
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_scrollView, _containerScrollView);
    
    [_scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(_scrollView.frame.size.width, CGRectGetHeight(_containerScrollView.frame))];
    _scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    _scrollView.delaysContentTouches = YES;
    
    [self.superview addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_scrollView]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:viewsDictionary]];
    [self.superview addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_scrollView]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:viewsDictionary]];
    [_scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_containerScrollView]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:viewsDictionary]];
    [_scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_containerScrollView]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:viewsDictionary]];
```

Somebody can explain me why doesn't it work?

Comment: Are the scrollView and the containerScrollView different sizes?  If they are the same size, the contentSize of the scroll view will dictate that no scrolling is necessary to view all of the content.

Comment: Yes, size is different.
_scrollview height : 652. 
_containerScrollView height : 1050

Comment: In autolayout, you generally don't specify the `contentSize` of a scroll view, because it is generally dictated by the constraints of the subviews. But, stepping back from that, perhaps you can just tell us what you're trying to achieve. It's hard to recommend solutions without understanding the bigger picture of the desired UX. E.g., what is the nature of the animation? How did you define the constraints of `_containerScrollView` (which I assume is a `UIView` inside the scroll view, not a `UIScrollView` itself)?

Comment: Well, the containerScrollView is a UIView which contains many UIViews. Actually, it's a right slide bar with many filters to display or not markers on a fullscreen map. In this slide bar I've a multiselect list. The aim of the animation is that when i tap on multiselect, the list slide down and views placed under, scroll too. To avoid that multiselect list come on foreground over filters

Answer (score 7):

Try to set your scrollView's Content size int "viewDidLayoutSubviews" method with keeping the autolayouts set.

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
  [self.itemList setContentSize:CGSizeMake(required_width, required_height)];
}
```